# Looping CSV files in VBA with paragraph marker

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a CSV file with paragraph marker at the end of every line, I have to loop the CSV file and copied to the excel sheet using VBA. Please find the below code which I am using,

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim row_number As Integer
Dim col_number As Integer
Dim lineFromFile As String
Dim lineItems As Variant

fileName = "D:\test.csv"

Open filePath For Input As #1

row_number = 1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, lineFromFile
    lineItems = Split(lineFromFile, ",")
    col_number = 1
    For i = 0 To 15
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(row_number).Columns(col_number + i).value = lineItems(i)
    row_number = row_number + 1
Loop
Close #1
```

[Image for CSV file showing paragraph marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H3AW.png)

What is the problem is EOF will be getting true when the controller reached paragraph marker at the end and it is reading only the first line. Please give some input on this.

Comment: Well you should first establish what the last EOF value is, and then do untill you reach that value, now you stop at one.

Comment: The 1 in the Do until EOF(1) is not the value or line number, it is identification of file. If I'm using the second file it will be Do until EOF(2).

Comment: Perhaps show more of your code including all the `Dim` statements, file opening, etc so we have a full understanding.

Comment: And a sample of your CSV file, cause it looks like the paragraph marker is seen as EOF by vba.

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43055 Looks like this problem also arose in 2005 already. How nifty such a tool named Google.

Comment: @Luuklag, Yes the same issue like I'm having but they give the solution for unix I have tried with my windows system not working.

Comment: @FreeMan, I think I have to repost for attaching CSV file and code. I have tried with comment not good.

Comment: You can click the edit button under your post.

Comment: @RameshRajagopal - what Luuklag said - hit the `edit` button below the `vba` tag. Do NOT post a duplicate. Also, take the [Tour] and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan and,Luuklag, I have edited my post please find the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this. I can't read the files by looping because of the line feed at the end. So I will split the lines and reading data by follows,

```
Line Input #1, lineFromFile
lines = Split(lineFromFile, vbLf)

For Each line In lines
  lineItems = Split(line, ",")
  Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(row_number).Columns(col_number + i).value = lineItems(i)
Next line
```

This is working fine for me. Thanks @FreeMan,Luuklag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exceptionally well versed in reading text files, but unless there's a way to change what VBA is seeing as the EOL marker, you'll have to read the file one character at a time, filling your own internal string buffer until you reach the paragraph marker.

i.e. Replace
`Line Input #1, lineFromFile`
with your own function  - something like this:
`lineFromFile = ReadALineFromMyFile(#1)`
that reads one character at a time and returns `lineFromFile` once it's found the paragraph marker.

Your code will then recognize that as "EOL" and can process the line buffer you've been filling.

Lather, rinse, repeat until you reach the true EOF.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan, but what is the problem here is once the control reached paragraph marker the EOF is set to true and the control come out from the loop. Not looping any other rows.